# Javascript: how to deal with a custom event if there is no handler?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am writing a 'drag-n-drop' library and want to create certain events for the user to hook on to. For example, before dropping an element onto another one, I create an event 'beforeDrop' with some data in the `details` field, and would like the user to be able to prevent the drop depending on the data. So, in an event handler created by the user, it could callback a library function (to actually do the drop) or not, depending on the data.

But if the user doesn't provide such a handler, the drop will never happen. I tried adding a default handler into the library, but there seems no way to guarantee the order that handlers are dealt with. Even if I add a timer to the library's handler, it still fires before the client's handler in Firefox (but not in Chrome).

```
document.addEventListener('beforeDrop', (e) => {
    setTimeout(doDrop(e), 50);  // I tried 500ms as well!
})
doDrop(e) {
    console.log('library: before drop: ' + e.detail.from + ' to ' + e.detail.to);
}
....
....
const event = new CustomEvent(beforeDrop, { detail: {from:fromDetail, to:toDetail}});
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63065750/js-customevent-with-callback-detail) which seems to be trying to do something similar, but there is no definite answer and it may be trying something more complex than I need.

Comment: Well, it has to be `setTimeout(() => doDrop(e), 50)`

Comment: yes, of course - so tied up with the events themselves I forget to do the timeout correctly.